# R - Text Formatting of Plot Text that is not hard-wired

Tags: r, plot, text-formatting

I would like to add formatted text to a plot (title, axes labels, legend, etc.). A standard solution would be e.g.

```
plot(1, 1, ylab=substitute(lambda[1]))
```

where the y-axis label will be the greek letter λ with subscript 1. That is what I want but unfortunatelly it is hard-wired. I would like it to be flexible, i.e. to have an option to pass the text as an argument of a function. So, looking at r help, I found that the argument for `substitute` is an expression. So I've tried

```
sometext <- "lambda[1]"
e <- parse(text="sometext")
plot(1, 1, ylab=substitute(e))
```

But `substitute` ignores that e is an object an simply prints the text 'e' as the label. So instead I tried

```
plot(1, 1, ylab=eval(e))
```

which was better because `eval` at least evaluates the expression but the label now is literally 'lambda[1]', i.e. it is not evaluated as a greek letter λ with a subscript.
I then explicitly stated that 'e' is an expression doing

```
e <- expression(sometext)
```

and running the two previous plot commands but with the same results as before.
The closest I came to what I wanted ot achieve was doing

```
plot(1, 1, ylab=substitute(var[i], list(var="lambda", i=1)))
```

where at least the 1 is printed as a subscript but the text 'lambda' instead of the greek letter λ is printed.

Any suggestions on how can I achieve what the first command does but not hard-wired? E.g. using a string and somehow converting it to the right object so that it will be displayed properly? Thanks.

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the label as an expression like so and then use `substitute` inside the function:

```
dwat <- function(expr){

plot(1, 1, ylab = substitute(expr))

}

dwat(lambda[1])
dwat(mu[2])
```

If you want to pass a string instead of an expression use `parse`:

```
dwat_string <- function(string){

plot(1, 1, ylab = parse(text = string))

}

dwat_string("mu[1]")
```

Another option would be to use the ellipsis approach. That way you can pass an xlab or any other argument to `plot`:

```
dwat2 <- function(...){

plot(1, 1, ...)

}

dwat2(ylab = expression(lambda[1]))
```

Comment: Here's a relevant r-help discussion with another option: http://r.789695.n4.nabble.com/R-How-to-pass-expression-as-an-argument-td808729.html

Comment: thanks. Your solution indeed provies more flexibility. I'd still prefer specifying the label using a string (if I needed to read the label from a csv file let's say) but maybe that's not possible. If nobody gives an answer I like more, I'll use your suggestion.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part about the string. Will edit response accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I was quite close I gave in then examples in my question. No need for `substitute` or `eval` in the `ylab` argument and I should have done `parse(text=sometext)`, i.e. no need for the quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

you were close, checks if this works

`substitute(lambda[i],list(i=i))`

Comment: Well, this produces the label I want but, it is hard-wired, i.e. I cannot programmatically change the lambda symbol to something else. So it works but not as I want it to. But, thanks.